# identify Dropdown element from website in Robotframework when there is no ID/Xpath/Value provided in website

Tags: robotframework

Not able to select a dropdown element using robotframework. There is no ID,xpath,css or value provided for the element its just class mentioned.

1. after clicking the menu button I need to select the webtrack user option which is the last option in the drop down but when inspected the element there is no id/xpath/css/value to identify the path. I have tried:

   ```
    Click Element    id=ctl00_ctl00_HeaderContentPlaceHolder_MainMenuCell
    Click Element    Xpath://a[@type='Webtrack User']
   ```

---

```html
<div class="rmSlide" style="visibility: visible; height: 463px; width: 232px; display: block; overflow: visible; left: 0px; top: 26px; z-index: 2;">
    <ul class="rmVertical rmGroup rmLevel1" style="display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; transition: none 0s ease 0s;">
       <li class="rmItem rmLast" style="z-index: 1;">
           <a class="rmLink OtherTile rmExpanded" href="#" style="width: 231px;">
              <img alt="" src="images/user-30px.png" class="rmLeftImage">
              <span class="rmText rmExpandRight">Webtrack User »</span>
           </a>
```

Need to select the element webtrack user from that dropdown.

Comment: Your `<a>` element does not have an ID, neither a type attribute. `Webtrack User` is the text of that element so you need something this: `//a[contains(.,'Webtrack User')]` or `//a[contains(text(),'Webtrack User')]`.

Comment: @BenceKaulics i have tried with both the syntax but nothing is working. I just need to click on that Webtrack user option. i tried with keywords like click element/select from list value but no way its identifying the Location. yes you are right no ID/xpath/CSS/value is provided . Only class name are given

Comment: Could it be that the element is on an iframe that needs to be selected first?

Comment: Got the solution @BenceKaulics . Just when inspecting the element using chrome "inspect" . On the highlighted line > just right click> select copy> select copy Xpath. Now paste the xpath in Script, this should identify properly and script won't fail.

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer then, with the actual xpath and such. :)